# Local Storage on Radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

While developping a survey, I use Local Storage to save given answers temporarily. It's working just fine, excpept for RadioButtons. Chrome's console shows that the values can be saved, till the reload button for showing the saved values is pressen. After pressing Reload, Local Storage won't change the saved value.

```
//Save Values
function save() {
    //Radiobuttons  
    var g1 = document.querySelector('input[name=erarbeiten]:checked').value;
    localStorage.setItem("g1", g1);

//Restoring saved Values
function reload(){
    // Radiobuttons    
    var G1 = document.getElementsByName('erarbeiten');
    var val1 = localStorage.getItem('g1');  
    for (var i = 0; i < G1.length; i++) {
        if (G1[i].value == val1) {
            G1[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

//Radiobuttons in the HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="erarbeiten" name="erarbeiten" value="Ja"><label for="erarbeiten">Ja</label>
<input type="radio" id="erarbeiten2" name="erarbeiten" value="Nein"><label for="erarbeiten2">Nein</label>
```

//buttons that call the functions

```
<button onclick="save()" type="button" class="buttonw" style="vertical-align:middle">Save me!</button>

<button onclick="reload()" type="button" class="buttonw" style="vertical-align:middle">Load me!</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList

Comment: You didn't provide nearly enough code. We have no HTML, no way to know how you want to go about calling these functions, and your reload function isn't even setup to run when you reload the page.

Comment: Please check your variables with console.log before storing and after retrieving.

Comment: Sry for not providing enough code, I assumed the functions would show he mistake. The actual problem was, that a few lines later 'document.getElementbyID('erarbeiten')'.value was used. I deleted that, now its working.

@zfrisch after reloading the page, the reload works just fine. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/krexkx15/7/

```
//call reload on page load
reload();

//add click functionality to radio buttons
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')).forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', save);
});

//Save Values
function save() {
  //Radiobuttons  
  var g1 = document.querySelector('input[name=erarbeiten]:checked');
  g1 = (g1) ? g1.value : '';
  localStorage.setItem("g1", g1);
}
//Restoring saved Values
function reload() {
  // Radiobuttons    
  // get a list of DOM elements
  var G1 = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('erarbeiten'));
  var val1 = localStorage.getItem('g1');
  for (var i = 0; i < G1.length; i++) {
    if (G1[i].value == val1) {
      G1[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @joseliese if this answered your question please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did answer my question, but while using the code provided, I get an error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

if I try to save the form and no Radiobutton is checked. Is there a workaround, too? Using an if-clause, checking for null doesn't work.

Comment: @Joseliese I updated the code in the answer. It now checks to make sure it can find a checked radio button with that name. You may want to consider using checkboxes instead of radio buttons if not making a selection is a valid option.

Comment: these Radiobuttons are necessary, because people have to choose. But they should have the option to save their status and go on later.

Comment: @Joseliese That's fine. It was a suggestion. I didn't know what the scope of what you were doing was.